# does not conform to protocol Decodable / Codable

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm using the following struct:

```
struct Item : Codable {

    var category:String
    var birthDate:Date
    var switch:Bool
    var weightNew: [Weight]
    var weightOld: Array<Double>
    var createdAt:Date
    var itemIdentifier:UUID
    var completed:Bool

    func saveItem() {
        DataManager.save(self, with: itemIdentifier.uuidString)
    }

    func deleteItem() { DataManager.delete(itemIdentifier.uuidString)
    }

    mutating func markAsCompleted() {
        self.completed = true
        DataManager.save(self, with: itemIdentifier.uuidString)
    }

}
```

And for weight:

```
struct Weight {
    var day:Int
    var weight:Double
    var type:Bool
}
```

After changing weightOld to weightNew I get two errors:
- Type 'Item' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
- Type 'Item' does not conform to protocol 'Codable'

If I leave out 'var weightNew: [Weight]' it works. Don't know what is happening and how to solve it... Help is appreciated.

Comment: `struct Weight: Codable { ... }`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Everything needs to be Codable. So far your `Weight` struct is not Codable. Update `Weight` to be Codable as well and then `Item` will be Codable.